# Can't highlight the same text within NSString using TTTAttributedLabel

Tags: ios, ios7, nsstring, ios8, tttattributedlabel

I'm new in iOS development and I'm trying to highlight a repetitive text inside a NSString using TTTAttributedLabel but always I obtain the first occurrence bolded. This is a little sample i'm using, what I'm doing wrong?. I'm not sure if the library is prepared to this kind of functionality.

```
UIView *viewOfSection1 = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 1700)];
viewOfSection1.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
KMSection *section1 = [[KMSection alloc] init];
section1.view = viewOfSection1;
section1.title = @"Some Title";
section1.colorForBackground = [UIColor whiteColor];

TTTAttributedLabel *label = [[TTTAttributedLabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 1700)];
label.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:14];
label.textColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];
label.lineBreakMode = LINE_BREAK_WORD_WRAP;
label.numberOfLines = 0;
label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentJustified;
[label setTextInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 40, 0, 7)];

NSString *text = @"This is text sample , text sample"

[label setText:text afterInheritingLabelAttributesAndConfiguringWithBlock:^ NSMutableAttributedString *(NSMutableAttributedString *mutableAttributedString) {
    NSRange boldRange = [[mutableAttributedString string] rangeOfString:@"text," options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];
    NSRange boldRange1 = [[mutableAttributedString string] rangeOfString:@"sample" options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];

    UIFont *boldSystemFont = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:14];
    CTFontRef font = CTFontCreateWithName((__bridge CFStringRef)boldSystemFont.fontName, boldSystemFont.pointSize, NULL);
    if (font) {
        [mutableAttributedString addAttribute:(NSString *)kCTFontAttributeName value:(__bridge id)font range:boldRange];
        [mutableAttributedString addAttribute:(NSString *)kCTFontAttributeName value:(__bridge id)font range:boldRange1];
        CFRelease(font);
    }

    return mutableAttributedString;
}];

[viewOfSection1 addSubview:label];

return @[section1];
```

The only way to perform what I'm looking for, was to separate the text in two parts and highlights the text separately.

Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 0):

This is because range of string only returns a single occurrence of the searching string, for multiple occurrence, you can try this out.

```
- (NSArray *)rangesOfString:(NSString *)searchString inString:(NSString *)str withOption:(NSStringCompareOptions)option{
    NSMutableArray *results = [NSMutableArray array];
    NSRange searchRange = NSMakeRange(0, [str length]);
    NSRange range = [str rangeOfString:searchString options:option range:searchRange];
    while (range.location != NSNotFound) {
        [results addObject:[NSValue valueWithRange:range]];
        searchRange = NSMakeRange(NSMaxRange(range), [str length] - NSMaxRange(range));
        range = [str rangeOfString:searchString options:option range:searchRange];
    }
    return results;
}
```

Then find the multiple occurrence in the string and make the text bold.

```
NSArray *rangeArr = [self rangesOfString:@"text" inString:mutableAttributedString.string withOption:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];
NSArray *rangeArr1 = [self rangesOfString:@"sample" inString:mutableAttributedString.string withOption:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];

NSMutableArray *boldArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:rangeArr];
[boldArray addObjectsFromArray:rangeArr1];

UIFont *boldSystemFont = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:14];
CTFontRef font = CTFontCreateWithName((__bridge CFStringRef)boldSystemFont.fontName, boldSystemFont.pointSize, NULL);
if (font) {
    for (NSValue *rangeValue in boldArray) {
        NSRange boldRange = rangeValue.rangeValue;
        [mutableAttributedString addAttribute:(NSString *)kCTFontAttributeName value:(__bridge id)font range:boldRange];
    }
    CFRelease(font);
}
```